# border-color: rgba() borders overlap at the corners giving a darker color than intended

Tags: css, rgba

Using the following code:

```
element{
    width:300px;
    border:9px solid;
    border-color:rgb(0,0,0);
    border-color:rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
}
```

I end up with corners that are darker due to the overlay of the two borders... the only way I have found around this is to add a `border-radius` equal to the width of the border. Are there any other work arounds?

I have only tested in chrome at the moment, I don't have my other browsers available right now.

Comment: I would also like to know, so here's an over-dramatized example: http://jsfiddle.net/4gutj/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very elegant, but you could make a wrapping `<div>` with a solid border and an opacity value: http://jsfiddle.net/4gutj/24/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="opacity-wrapper">
  <div class="transparent-border">Foo</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.transparent-border {
    width:300px;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 10px;

    text-align: center;

    border:30px solid;
    border-color:rgb(0,0,0);
    border-color:rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);

    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.opacity-wrapper {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0.7;

    padding: 30px;
    width:320px;
}

.opacity-wrapper div {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);

    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for something more elegant, but this was the best I could come up with as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use `border-spacing` on your table like so:

```
table
{
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Combine with some nice CSS selectors to keep borders from overlapping (see below). This will apply to all tds except the last one.

```
table td:not(:last-child)
{

}
```

### See [Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/SCBB4/)

Then you can use rgba borders without overlap.

Comment: Most elegant solution imo

Answer (score 2):

Also not very elegant but works is:

```
element{
    width:300px;
    border:9px solid;
    border-top-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0,0,0 0.7);
    border-right-color: rgba(1,1,1, 0.7);
    border-left-color: rgba(1,1,1 0.7);
}
```

The color differences cause the colors to meet at a 45% angle.  You can also create bevels like this.

Answer (score 2):

Since most [browsers support](http://caniuse.com/css-boxshadow) box-shadow, you can use it like that:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
```